# Laravel Query Builder "issue" don't returns me the original default sorting values from database field

Tags: laravel, sorting, builder

```
|    ID    |    name    |    link    |
      1          one         good
      2          two        allow
      3         tree         data
      4         four         last
      5         five         rade

$data = DB::table('info')->plunk('link');
```

Ok This request gives me the link fields with this sort by default:

- data
- last
- good
- rade
- allow

And not with the right way - original sorting like as you can see in the table field:

- good
- allow
- data
- last
- rade

My queston is..
How can take the link fields as is from the database? You know, the original sorting without give to my code the sorting method like:

```
->orderBy('id', 'asc')
```

Just the original.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on "natural sorting". That sorting can change unexpectedly. What is wrong with `orderBy`?

Comment: The wrong is not with the orderBy but with the Laravel, The SQL system gives you the original sorting, but laravel not. The second wrong, i don't want execute more code, you know, more code, more time to load! So how can resolve this very important issue in Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

> The wrong is not with the orderBy but with the Laravel, The SQL system gives you the original sorting, but laravel not. The second wrong, i don't want execute more code, you know, more code, more time to load! So how can resolve this very important issue in Laravel?

Natural sorting is unpredictable and that is why you sort by IDs. To accomplish what you want *reliably*, you should use `orderBy`. If you try to rely on natural sorting, you will introduce many headaches and problems. It is not Laravel's fault that natural sorting is unpredictable.

Sorting will not significantly impact performance in any way, especially if that table is indexed by ID. If you are unsure how to index a column, please read:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-indexes.html

You will not be able to accomplish what you need here without using an `order by` clause. The very nature of your question is requesting an order. Luckily, your `ID` column is a perfectly viable way of doing this.

Comment: Thank you, now i'm sure the SQL don't have a default sorting, in fact, this is my question.